# Using nested vcs +incdir+

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, synopsys-vcs

I have a situation where I need to package a SystemVerilog environment and export it to a customer. I need to make sure I provide as few `+incdir+` as possible for the customer to compile.

The environment is huge, and it contains many IPs and hence there are lot of directories that need to be included.

I want to know if there is any easy way to add incdir for compilation that includes directories of all the IPs?

I was thinking of add a file `abc.txt` in each of the IPs that contain +incdir and having a top.txt that includes all the abc.txt from all the IPs. It did not work.

This is what I tried

f: `abc.txt`

```
+incdir+tb_top.sv
+incdir+ip1/abc.txt
+incdir+ip2/abc.txt
```

f:`ip1/abc.txt`

```
+incdir+a.sv
+incdir+b.sv
```

f:`ip2/abc.txt`

```
+incdir+a.sv
+incdir+b.sv
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the `+incdir+` simulation command compile option.  `incdir` is short for "include directory".  You are using **file** names, but you need to use **directory** names, like:

```
+incdir+ip1
+incdir+ip2
```

Keep in mind that `incdir` is only used for searching directories for files included using the `` `include `` compiler directive inside a Verilog source code file:

```
module m;
    `include "parameters.v"
    // ...
endmodule
```

Look at the VCS documentation for `-y` and `+libext+` also.

Comment: Also look at -f and -F

Answer (score 0):

+incdir+ specifies a list of directories where to look for included files. No plain files can be used as its arguments.

Potentially vcs `-f` qualifier allows nested use, so you can have:
a.txt

```
+incdir+inc1
top.sv
-f inc1/b.txt
```

There is an issue though, the +incdir+ resolves non-absolute paths relative to execution PWD which has nothing to do with location of the '-f' txt file. So, you either have to fix relative paths for IPs or use absolute paths. The latter does not work well in customer delivery.

Another issue you can hit is that multiple IPs might have include file named the same, but located in different paths. And it could contain different contents for different IPs. In this respect the global *order* of +incdir+ is very important.

By default vcs produces a list of parsed files, e.g.,

```
Parsing design file 'top.sv'
Parsing included file 'inc1/inc1.svh'.
Parsing included file 'inc1/inc2/inc2.svh'.
Back to file 'inc1/inc1.svh'.
Back to file 'top.sv'.
```

potentially you can parse vcs log and extract all files it consumes in the right order. From there a list of +incdir+s could be produced.